# After ng build --prod index.html file is not generating?

Tags: angular, typescript

I updated the angular 7 to  8.2.1 after i build my project on production mode the dist folder does not generate `index.html` file

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "paths": {
      "exceljs": [
        "node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs.min"
      ]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],

  }
}
```

[image: Dist/AssetMang/]
**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "AssetMang": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/AssetMang",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "8mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "port": 4204,
            "browserTarget": "AssetMang:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "AssetMang:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AssetMang:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "AssetMang-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "AssetMang:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "AssetMang:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "AssetMang"
}
```

Comment: See if you are missing something https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0

Comment: @SGalea checked,nothing is missing.

Comment: Can you share your angular.json

Comment: @TonyNgo please check

Comment: Does your normal src/index.html exist?

Comment: @Flix yes it exist when i only build the app using ng build its generates the index.html file

Answer (score 21):

As explained in issue [15175](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15175#issuecomment-517260507), check your build output. If there is an error or budget violations, the `index.html` file will not be generated.

```sh
Build at: 2021-07-11T22:17:50.237Z - Hash: 085ada49cbe5750a0a86 - Time: 47523ms

Warning: initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 500.00 kB was not met by 559.07 kB with a total of 1.03 MB.

Error: initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 1.00 MB was not met by 35.07 kB with a total of 1.03 MB.
```

The build must succeed for the index to be generated.

Comment: THIS, it took me 3 hours to figure out what was going wrong, I thought I could just ignore the warnings.