ng build --configuration production causes This call to "require" will not be bundled because the argument is not a string literal
After doing some research, I still can't find a fix to my issue. After updating npm, angular, node(because I saw https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/27674) and increasing maximumError budget(because I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/68340281/10464730) and if I'm not mistaken I also already did a project update to include ssr but the issue still exist. Here's the output when I do a

ng build --configuration production --verbose

:

Building...
polyfills-FFHMD2TL.js  33.7kb
⚡ Done in 31ms
polyfills.server.mjs  262.3kb
⠙ Building...
main-K43KHCE6.js  217.9kb
⠸ Building... ● [DEBUG] This call to "require" will not be bundled
because the argument is not a string literal
[unsupported-require-call]
node_modules/express/lib/view.js:72:13:
  72 │     var fn = require(mod).__express;
     ╵              ~~~~~~~ ⠼ Building...

server.mjs                 1.1mb ⚠️   chunk-DPD2CJOV.mjs
525.3kb   chunk-SNU752KB.mjs        12.4kb   chunk-VCVCHJZV.mjs        11.8kb   chunk-5XUXGTUW.mjs         2.5kb   render-utils.server.mjs    1.4kb   main.server.mjs            149b
Browser bundles Initial chunk files     | Names               |  Raw
size | Estimated transfer size main-K43KHCE6.js        | main
| 223.11 kB |                59.65 kB polyfills-FFHMD2TL.js   |
polyfills           |  34.52 kB |                11.28 kB
styles-WCBAZ6MA.css     | styles              |   1.16 kB |
337 bytes
                    | Initial total       | 258.78 kB |                71.26 kB

Server bundles Initial chunk files     | Names               |  Raw
size server.mjs              | server              |   1.11 MB |
chunk-DPD2CJOV.mjs      | -                   | 537.95 kB |
polyfills.server.mjs    | polyfills.server    | 268.60 kB |
chunk-SNU752KB.mjs      | -                   |  12.68 kB |
chunk-5XUXGTUW.mjs      | -                   |   2.55 kB |
render-utils.server.mjs | render-utils.server |   1.46 kB |
main.server.mjs         | main.server         | 149 bytes |
Lazy chunk files        | Names               |  Raw size
chunk-VCVCHJZV.mjs      | xhr2                |  12.07 kB |
Prerendered 1 static route. Application bundle generation complete.
[5.198 seconds]

Btw, ng serve is working just fine on my local
Here's my package.json:
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:my-project-name": "node dist/my-project-name/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/ssr": "^18.2.11",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "my-project-name": "file:",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.11",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

And here's my environment details:

Angular CLI: 18.2.11 Node: 20.12.2 Package Manager: npm 10.9.0 OS:
win32 x64
Angular: 18.2.11 ... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli,
core, forms ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic,
platform-server ... router, ssr


Why are you bundling express? Are you writing an HTTP server?

I actually don't remember why I have that. Do I need to remove it?

After removing express, I'm still getting the same issue

@rminaj How did you remove it? "express" is there is presumably because you have SSR enabled in the project. Is this intended? If not, you need to remove ssr properly. If you need ssr, please, provide a way to reproduce, it needs to be debugged to fully understand what happens on your side

I checked my old commits and it seems like I have express and ssr from the very beginning. Will try to remove them and test again

@EricMORAND, if you need SSR, you actually need express.
"The server.ts file configures a Node.js Express server and Angular server-side rendering. CommonEngine is used to render an Angular application."
https://angular.dev/guide/ssr#configure-server-side-rendering

@VladLego okay but what he is bundling? The web application - that doesn't require express - or the server - that requires it.

@EricMORAND the web application in SSR (server side render) enabled apps includes the server part, which is express.
This call to "require" will not be bundled because the argument is not a string literal [unsupported-require-call] is a warning - which looks like it's a node issue, not angular related.
ng serve doesn't use express - but serving with ssr is via express. If you need SSR, the server side code is required.

A very unsatisfying answer but worked. After finding this, I tried creating a new project and just transferred my source code and assets to the new one and it worked. Oh, and I guess the important part, I opted out of SSR during generation.
